# How do I install the Elasticache cluster client for php7 in elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

How do I install the Elasticache cluster client for php7 in elasticbeanstalk?  Pecl doesn't seem to be installed and the file download is a zip file instead of a .tgz like it has been for previous releases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're on a Linux system (from your preference of .tgz), I suggest that you use **unzip**.  If you don't already have it, there are various implementations and free downloads.  First, be sure that you're getting the proper version for your distribution (OS type and version).